# Do Spark-NLP pretrained pipelines only work on linux systems?

Tags: johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I am trying to set up a simple code where I pass a dataframe and test it with the pretrained explain pipeline provided by johnSnowLabs Spark-NLP library. 
I am using jupyter notebooks from anaconda and have a spark scala kernet setup using apache toree. Everytime I run the step where it should load the pretrained pipeline, it throws a tensorflow error. Is there a way we can run this on windows locally?

```
I was trying this in a maven project earlier and the same error had happened. Another colleague tried it on a linux system and it worked. Below is the code I have tried and the error that it gave.


import org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel
import com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.pretrained.PretrainedPipeline
import com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.SparkNLP
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("test")
    .master("local[*]")
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "4G")
    .config("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "200M")
    .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
    .getOrCreate()

val testData = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
    (1, "Google has announced the release of a beta version of the popular TensorFlow machine learning library"),
    (2, "Donald John Trump (born June 14, 1946) is the 45th and current president of the United States"))).toDF("id", "text")
val pipeline = PretrainedPipeline("explain_document_dl", lang = "en") //this is where it gives error
val annotation = pipeline.transform(testData)

  annotation.show()

  annotation.select("entities.result").show(false)
```

Below error occurs:

> Name: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException Message: Spark NLP tried
>   to load a Tensorflow Graph using Contrib module, but failed to load it
>   on this system. If you are on Windows, this operation is not
>   supported. Please try a noncontrib model. If not the case, please
>   report this issue. Original error message:
>
> Op type not registered 'BlockLSTM' in binary running on
>   'MyMachine'. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the
>   binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved
>   graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.)
>   `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as
>   contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.
>   StackTrace:  Op type not registered 'BlockLSTM' in binary running on
>   'MyMachine'. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the
>   binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved
>   graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.)
>   `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as
>   contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.
>   at
>   com.johnsnowlabs.ml.tensorflow.TensorflowWrapper$.readGraph(TensorflowWrapper.scala:163)
>   at
>   com.johnsnowlabs.ml.tensorflow.TensorflowWrapper$.read(TensorflowWrapper.scala:202)
>   at
>   com.johnsnowlabs.ml.tensorflow.ReadTensorflowModel$class.readTensorflowModel(TensorflowSerializeModel.scala:73)
>   at
>   com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.annotators.ner.dl.NerDLModel$.readTensorflowModel(NerDLModel.scala:134)
>   at
>   com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.annotators.ner.dl.ReadsNERGraph$class.readNerGraph(NerDLModel.scala:112)
>   at
>   com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.annotators.ner.dl.NerDLModel$.readNerGraph(NerDLModel.scala:134)
>   at
>   com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.annotators.ner.dl.ReadsNERGraph$$anonfun$2.apply(NerDLModel.scala:116)
>   at
>   com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.annotators.ner.dl.ReadsNERGraph$$anonfun$2.apply(NerDLModel.scala:116)
>   at
>   com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.ParamsAndFeaturesReadable$$anonfun$com$johnsnowlabs$nlp$ParamsAndFeaturesReadable$$onRead$1.apply(ParamsAndFeaturesReadable.scala:31)
>   at
>   com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.ParamsAndFeaturesReadable$$anonfun$com$johnsnowlabs$nlp$ParamsAndFeaturesReadable$$onRead$1.apply(ParamsAndFeaturesReadable.scala:30)
>   at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>   at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48) 
>   at
>   com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.ParamsAndFeaturesReadable$class.com$johnsnowlabs$nlp$ParamsAndFeaturesReadable$$onRead(ParamsAndFeaturesReadable.scala:30)
>   at
>   com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.ParamsAndFeaturesReadable$$anonfun$read$1.apply(ParamsAndFeaturesReadable.scala:41)
>   at
>   com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.ParamsAndFeaturesReadable$$anonfun$read$1.apply(ParamsAndFeaturesReadable.scala:41)
>   at
>   com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.FeaturesReader.load(ParamsAndFeaturesReadable.scala:19)
>   at
>   com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.FeaturesReader.load(ParamsAndFeaturesReadable.scala:8)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.util.DefaultParamsReader$.loadParamsInstance(ReadWrite.scala:652)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$SharedReadWrite$$anonfun$4.apply(Pipeline.scala:274)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$SharedReadWrite$$anonfun$4.apply(Pipeline.scala:272)
>   at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>   at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>   at
>   scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
>   at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
>   at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234) 
>   at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$SharedReadWrite$.load(Pipeline.scala:272)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$PipelineModelReader.load(Pipeline.scala:348)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$PipelineModelReader.load(Pipeline.scala:342)
>   at
>   com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.pretrained.ResourceDownloader$.downloadPipeline(ResourceDownloader.scala:135)
>   at
>   com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.pretrained.ResourceDownloader$.downloadPipeline(ResourceDownloader.scala:129)
>   at com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.pretrained.PretrainedPipelin`enter code
>   here`e.(PretrainedPipeline.scala:14)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked, there is an NER model inside that pipeline. That NER model was trained by using TensorFlow and it has some `contrib` code inside which is only compatible with Unix-based OS such as Linux and macOS. There is an open issue here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26468

For that purpose, they have released some **Windows-compatible** pipelines which are named `noncontrib`. You can change the name of the pipeline to the following:

```
val pipeline = PretrainedPipeline("explain_document_dl_noncontrib", lang = "en")
```

The source for all pre-trained pipelines:
https://nlp.johnsnowlabs.com/docs/en/pipelines

**Full disclosure**: I am one of the contributors to the Spark NLP library.

**UPDATE**: Since the release of Spark NLP `2.4.0`, all the models and pipelines are now cross-platform: https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp-models

This should work on Linux, macOS and Windows if you are using Spark NLP 2.4.0 release:

```scala
val pipeline = PretrainedPipeline("explain_document_dl", lang = "en")
```

**UPDATE 2022**: With the exception of M1 and aarch64 architectures (for now), all the 5000+ models/pipelines are compatible with Windows (8, 10, and 11), Linux (Ubuntu, Debian, CentOS, and etc.), and macOS operating systems.
Spark NLP Models Hub: https://nlp.johnsnowlabs.com/models