# How to install offline Spark NLP packages

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

How can I install offline Spark NLP packages without internet connection.
I've downloaded the package (`recognizee_entities_dl`) and uploaded it to the cluster.

I've installed Spark NLP using `pip install spark-nlp==2.5.5`.
I'm using PySpark and from the cluster I'm unable to download the packages.

Already tried;

```
pipeline = PretrainedPipeLine.from_disk('/path/to/recognize_entities_dl')
pipeline = PretrainedPipeLine.load('/path/to/recognize_entities_dl')
```

Errors:

```
'PretrainedPipeline' has no attribute 'load'

Input path does not exist:
    hdfs://...../recognize_entities_dl_en_2.4.3_2.4_1584626752821/metatdata
```

Comment: Please add more details, whether you are using Scala Spark or Pyspark? If you are using pyspark, you can always use pip install package_name_downloaded before the start of your application on each node. Ideally, you should install when the cluster is created, installing through docker images is one other option

Comment: So, you have installed everything already but are having trouble loading the pretrained recognize entity model from the disk? Do you get any error?

Comment: What Spark version are you using? Also, you can check if the file exists using `hdfs dfs -ls /path/to/...`.

Comment: Why do you load the model? Because your Apache Spark version <2.4.x? For 2.4.X the code shall be: pipeline = PretrainedPipeline('/path/to/recognize_entities_dl')

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58522742/unable-to-download-the-pipeline-provided-by-spark-nlp-library - This Might help you

Comment: path does not exist maybe because your package name does not match with the package name you have given in your path. Your downloaded package name is 'recognizee_entities_dl' with double e and your path has only one e `/path/to/recognize_entities_dl'` . can you check and confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your error:

```
 hdfs://...../recognize_entities_dl_en_2.4.3_2.4_1584626752821/metatdata
```

**metatdata** you should change to **metadata** by removing one extra "t".

Also, You see **2.4.3** in "recognize_entities_dl_en_**2.4.3**_2.4_1584626752821"

This indicates it is for **Spark NLP 2.4.3**

But, In the question, you have mentioned you are using,

`spark-nlp==2.5.5`

Which is okay as long as

```
2.5.5 >= 2.4.3
```

But sometimes it causes issues.

Also **2.4** in "recognize_entities_dl_en_2.4.3_**2.4**_1584626752821"

This indicates it is for **Apache Spark 2.4**

**The Spark NLP library built and compiled against Apache Spark 2.4.x. That is why models and pipelines are only available for the 2.4.x version.**